# Prevent deleting a row in Infopath 2010 repeating table

Tags: microsoft-infopath

How can I prevent a user from deleting any rows in Infopath? I just want them to be able to add new rows and make updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can...  Usually the permissions to change and/or add ("edit") means you can also delete (since you could always edit it to be blank/empty anyway).

Here are your permission choices according to the [MS Office on-line help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/create-a-form-that-has-restricted-permission-HA010077998.aspx#BM3):

> Users or groups can be given a set of permissions according to the access levels assigned to them by authors using the Permission dialog box, as outlined in the following list:
>
> - **Read**:    Users with Read access can read a form, but they don't have permission to edit, print, or copy the form.
> - **Change**:    Users with Change access can read, edit, and save changes to a form, but they don't have permission to print the form.
> - **Full Control**:    Users with Full Control access have full authoring permissions and can do anything with the form that the form author can do, such as set expiration dates for content, prevent printing, and give permissions to users. Form authors always have Full Control access.

From [infopathdev.com's forums](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/16814/59111.aspx#59111):

> If you want to prevent them from deleting data in items within a
>   repeating table there are several techniques:
>
> 1. Disable inserts and deletes the table
>
>    > TODO: double click repeating table blue button in the designer and under default settings uncheck
>    >     allow inserts and deletes **Pros:** easy to do  **Cons:** heavy-handed
> 2. Make fields read-only
>
>    > TODO: double click the cells in each column and check read-only on Display tab **Pros:** easy to do  **Cons:** can't add
>    >     data to cells, but rows can still be inserted or deleted
> 3. Disable inserts and deletes using a condition
>
>    > TODO: double click the repeating table blue button in the designer and add a conditional
>    >     formatting rule to disable insert/delete **Pros:** easy to do, you can use
>    >     the expression condition of "1=1" to make it always true **Cons:** only
>    >     good for read only items, but you can add a button to insert new items
>    >     if you use qRules
> 4. Make previously entered rows read-only
>
>    > TODO: add a conditional formatting rule that makes the value read-only based on some condition
>    >     (for example, already entered data) **Pros:** supports entering new data 
>    >     **Cons:** last row is editable until new row is added, semi-complex xpath
>    >     required to compare current index of row with count of table to allow
>    >     entering new data, but easy

Comment: Is it not possible to do using Rules or do I have to resort to custom code? I'm surprised they haven't made it more customizable. I'm looking at http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/16814.aspx which is helpful.

Comment: It's been a while since I used InfoPath, but I'm pretty sure the "Rules" apply to the forms themselves (rules the form follows when "X" happens) and have nothing to do with users' access to change the forms.

Comment: I'm referring to the repeating table when they're filling out the form (not designing it). They can delete data far too easily. I'm going to remove the table and just it show one record at a time.

Comment: I think the things in that link you provided are probably your best bets.

Comment: I added the info from that link to my answer, for future users' sake.  Sorry I can't come up with anything easier for ya. :(